# How do I change text alingment in DOORS?

Tags: text-alignment, ibm-doors

## Question

Within a single DOORS object, how do I change the text alignment from any menu or tool option? I am using DOORs 9.5.

## Research

The [first result on google](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014699288) only talks about soft versus hard returns, [this prominent IBM Jazz page](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/235977/doors-ng-602-align-left-in-contents-column-not-working) doesn't talk about an application I use and [this answer from the IBM community](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014443296) requires DXL usage, which my team does not have permission to access.  I am simply looking for the option that changes text alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of ways: First the Object Text needs to be in Edit-In-Place. 
1) From the toolbar press the indent icon..

2) From the menu:
Edit>In-Place>Increase (or) Decrease Indent

in DXL, the command is applyTextFormattingToParagraph(),

Hope this helps..
Don

Comment: I should note, this essentially solved my problem, hence the upvote and accept.  However, there were some table cells where this method did nothing.  This comment is here to point out that sometimes a table cell will be noncooperative with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

For tables, I think what you are looking for is for Table>Properties... from there you can set the justification. Cells don't indent, as such. I think that numbers default to left or maybe to center justification and text to right when imported from word tables. See if that does the trick.